# Mapping row-wise sorted dataframe to original column labels (Pandas)

Tags: python, sorting, dataframe, row

I am facing this problem involving dataframes, so after spending a lot of time on Google, I am opening a question here.
I am having a Dataframe -

```
df 
   A  B  C   D
0  8  3  6   2
1  1 -3  5   2
2  4  9  5  10
3  2 -4 -8  -2
```

I want to sort every row in descending order, *but instead of saving the values*, I want to save the corresponding column name.

Sorted dataframe would look like this -

```
df 
       A  B  C   D
    0  8  6  3   2
    1  5  2  1  -3
    2 10  9  5   4
    3  2 -2 -4  -8
```

**What I ultimately want is this structure below,** which corresponds to the column indices of the sorted dataframe `df`  -

```
df_col 
       1  2  3   4
    0  A  C  B   D
    1  C  D  A   B
    2  D  B  C   A
    3  A  D  B   C
```

I am sure there will be a simpler one liner solution to this problem, without coding an explicit `for loop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `np.argsort`, sort the indices, and then index into `df.columns`.

```
In [129]: pd.DataFrame(df.columns[df.apply(np.argsort, axis=1).T[::-1].T])
Out[129]: 
   0  1  2  3
0  A  C  B  D
1  C  D  A  B
2  D  B  C  A
3  A  D  B  C
```

Comment: Oh! I am a newbie here, but have maked it as 'accepted' now. Many thanks once again.

Comment: @OliverS It's alright. You aren't obligated to do so but consider it a nice way of saying "thanks" :) You can only mark one answer accepted so always choose the one that helped you the most.

Comment: Sure definitely! Will slowly slowly get more accustomed to stackoverflow etiquettes :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

```
print (np.argsort(-df.values, axis=1))
[[0 2 1 3]
 [2 3 0 1]
 [3 1 2 0]
 [0 3 1 2]]
 
print (df.columns.values[np.argsort(-df.values, axis=1)])
Index([['A', 'C', 'B', 'D'], ['C', 'D', 'A', 'B'], ['D', 'B', 'C', 'A'],
       ['A', 'D', 'B', 'C']],
      dtype='object')
      
print (pd.DataFrame(df.columns.values[np.argsort(-df.values, axis=1)], 
                               index=df.index))

   0  1  2  3
0  A  C  B  D
1  C  D  A  B
2  D  B  C  A
3  A  D  B  C
```

Or pandas solution with `apply`:

```
print (df.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=False).index, axis=1))
   A  B  C  D
0  A  C  B  D
1  C  D  A  B
2  D  B  C  A
3  A  D  B  C
```

Comment: It works as well, as your other solution. Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is more faster, because using only numpy.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution similar to @COLDSPEED's solution - it uses `Series.argsort`:

```
In [130]: df.apply(lambda x: df.columns[x.argsort()[::-1]], axis=1)
Out[130]:
   A  B  C  D
0  A  C  B  D
1  C  D  A  B
2  D  B  C  A
3  A  D  B  C
```

Comment: Hallo MaxU, your solution works equally well. Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: Can this problem be extended by only having the column indices of those values which are greater than 0? So in the second row we only get C D A and empty space. In the final row only A.

Comment: @OliverS, please open a new question with a small sample data set and desired data set. Changing questions that were already answered - invalidates given answers

Comment: I just did so Max.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way, using `argsort` and `apply`

```
In [1000]: np.argsort(-df, axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.index[x], axis=1)
Out[1000]:
   A  B  C  D
0  A  C  B  D
1  C  D  A  B
2  D  B  C  A
3  A  D  B  C
```

Comment: Thanks John for the solution.